# Notation for submatrix

Tags: matrices, notation

Consider a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and another matrix, termed the index matrix, $B\in\{0,1\}^{n\times m}$.

What is the appropriate notation for a submatrix of $A$, call it $C$, built from the elements of $B$ that are one. Is $C=A(B)$ accepted?

Is there a better (more accepted) way to write this?

Comment: You just made a notation. But instead of round brackets use something else, say, $A[B]$

Comment: There is more than one way to interpret what you want. It would be helpful to edit your question to include a minimal example as well as the intended audience. If your are addressing the HPC community, then there is likely a standard notation already.